# CQL table design for temporal data

Tags: cassandra, cql

As a Cassandra novice, I have a CQL design question. I want to re-use a concept which I've build before using RDBMS systems, to create history for customerData. The customer himself will only see the latest version, so that should be the fastest, but queries on whole history can be performed.

My suggested entity properties:

customerId text,
validFromDate   date,
validUntilDate  date,
customerData text

- First save of customerData just INSERTs customerData with validFromDate=NOW and validUntilDate=31-12-9999
- Subsequent saves of customerData changes the last record - setting validUntilDate=NOW - and INSERT new customerData with validFromDate=NOW and validUntilDate=31-12-9999

Result:

- This way a query of (customerId, validUntilDate)=(id,31-12-9999) will give last saved version.
- Query on (customerId) will give all history.
- To query customerData at certain time t just use query with validFromDate < t < validUntilDate

My guess is PARTITION_KEY = customerId and CLUSTER_KEY can be validFromDate. Or use PRIMARY KEY = customerId.  Or I could create two tables, one for fast querying of lastest version (has no history), and another for historical analyses.

How do you design this in CQL-way? I think I'm thinking too much RDBMish.

Comment: I am afraid that PARTITION_KEY = customerId and CLUSTER_KEY= validDate can cause a fat row assuming that a customer can have lots of history data(>100 mb) ...if that is the case then it would be good if you think of doing  time based bucketing of partition ....  during modeling just make sure your model satisfy all the queries you want to execute...if you wanna perfrom multiple analysis on history data it would be difficult to handle with cassandra alone you may need to introduce spark in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use change timestamp as CLUSTERING KEY with DESC order, e.g

```
   CREATE TABLE customer_data_versions (
    id text,
    change_time timestamp,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, change_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( change_time DESC );
```

It will allow you to store data versions per customer id in descending order.

Insert two versions for the same id:

```
INSERT INTO customer_data_versions (id, change_time, name) VALUES ('id1', totimestamp(now()),'John'); 
INSERT INTO customer_data_versions (id, change_time, name) VALUES ('id1', totimestamp(now()),'John Doe');
```

Get last saved version:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_data_versions WHERE id='id1' LIMIT 1;
```

Get all versions for the id:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_data_versions WHERE id='id1';
```

Get versions between dates:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_data_versions WHERE id='id1' AND change_time <= before_date AND change_time >= after_date;
```

Please note, there are [some limits for partition size](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html) (how much versions you will be able to store per customer id):

> Cells in a partition: ~2 billion (231); single column value size: 2 GB ( 1 MB is recommended)